# Popen can't find batch file available on command line

Tags: python, popen, windowserror

I'm trying to execute a program which is available to my command prompt but isn't in Python.

Command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Documents\libexe\tfc\bin\Debug>asc-dir
asc-dir.: directory not linked to an ASC directory //Expected output
```

Test Script:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('asc-dir', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(result, err) = proc.communicate()

print(result)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 1
06, in exec_file
    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 8
2, in exec_code
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Users\mryan.\git\web\PBNBApi\pbnb_cli\test.py", lin
e 9, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen('asc-dir', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: shell=True is the way to go, another option is adding the bat extension: proc = subprocess.Popen('asc-dir.bat', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I needed to set `shell=True`

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('asc-dir', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(result, err) = proc.communicate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running through some Visual Studio extension. Maybe it fiddles with the PATH env var passed to python? As such, you may need to specify the absolute path.

```
import os
print os.environ['PATH']
```